# Is there any way to point for Selenium server which FF to use?

Tags: selenium

I have very old FF version on my PC, but I'm not able to update it to run selenium tests on my PC. At the same time I need more modern FF version to run selenium-standalone-server.

Is it possible to somehow point which FF (path to FF directory) should use selenium server?

Answer (score 0):

Update the PATH variable with the location of firefox folder which you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the browser version using Firefox Profile.

```
 FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
 fp.setPreference("webdriver.firefox.bin", "Binary path of Firefox"); 
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fp);
```

Or

```
 FirefoxBinary fb = new FirefoxBinary("Binary path of Firefox");
 FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
 //Using fp you can set your own profile if want
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fb, fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox binary lets you run tests on your favorite Firefox versions.

Follow the steps below:

1. Install multiple versions of Firefox in your PC.
2. Make sure the installed Firefox versions on different path locations using Custom installation

## JAVA

> import java.io.File; import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
> import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
> import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
>
> private WebDriver driver;
>
> FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("C://Program Files//Mozilla Firefox26//firefox.exe"));
> FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
> driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);

## PYTHON

> from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
>
> driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary("C://Program Files//Mozilla Firefox26//firefox.exe"))